# jQuery framework for building prototypes

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, zurb-foundation

I would like to know if there are alternative solutions to

ZURB FONDATION 
http://foundation.zurb.com

for building prototypes in jQuery.
I need:
- Grid
- UI elements

If you use nay please give me your opinions and feec back on:
- easy to use
- cross platform cross/browser

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zurb Foundation is great, I'm using it on all of my projects now. For those that like more 'canned' styles there is Twitter Bootstrap.

Comment: any links?  what is foundation?

Comment: Foundation is a stellar responsive design and rapid prototyping CSS/HTML/js framework. http://foundation.zurb.com

Twitter bootstrap has similar offerings, but I find has too much canned styles for my taste. I prefer to do my own graphics.
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/